# Check if an element is in a jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element, and a jQuery set. I would like to check if the element is inside the jQuery set. I need a condition like this.

```
if ($someUL.find("> li > a").contains(myElement)) {
  ...
}
```

Here, the `contains` method does not exist, I used it to demonstrate my goal. I'm aware of several methods similar to this, like `has`, `is`, `$.contains`, but all of them has different meaning.

Comment: `if ($someUL.find("> li > a").filter(myElement).length)`???  Now i'm not sure what is your exact expected behaviour?! And what about just use: `$someUL.find(myElement).length`? Because depending your use case and relevant HTML markup, it could be enough. Now for sure you'd have better to provide a MCVE in question itself

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you, yes your suggestion works too, but I prefer using `index` for this.

Comment: And doesn't it work for you: `myElement.is($someUL.find("> li > a"))` ?

Comment: Hm, I didn't know that `is` can accept another jQuery object as parameter. That looks also good, however, I should wrap `myElement` to be jQuery too.

Comment: Ya, i didn't know what was `myElement`

Comment: The naming tried to be self explanatory, and I've also declared it at the beginning of my post :)

Comment: Ya but we never know... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.index()` method here. If the element is not found in set, `.index()` will return -1.:

```
if($someUL.find("> li > a").index(myElement) > -1){
   //myelement exists in set $someUL.find("> li > a")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, this is nicer for this question than using `filter` IMO. Also, this should be slightly more efficient as far as performance  goes.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: glad it helps :), don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your answer by reading the [jQuery API](http://devdocs.io/jquery/).

I think your aim is to check the elememt whether match the selector.The answer is to use `.is()`.

According the API:

- `.has()` is used in Promise and is **experimental technology**
- `.contain()` or `$.contain()` was judged the descendant
- `.is()` can be used to decide the selector, elements or selection even if function.

so, you should use `.is()` here is [API](http://devdocs.io/jquery/is)

Comment: Thank you for the summary, I didn't know that `is` can accept another jQuery object to check containment. However, for this simple task when I have an exact DOM element, using `index` is better approach IMO. But you definitely god my upvote.

Comment: And also, please forgive me that I didn't have a free week to read the jQuery API :)

Comment: Before your question, I never use the `.has()`. After your question, I get the understand of `.has()` function, There maybe a lot of answers to your question, choose the best. I learn a lot from others' answers :)